# Gradle custom task option without value

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm developing a custom gradle task and i'd like to have an option which does act like a flag and doesn't require a value.

I just want to check if it is set

Basically : I can use plugin either `gradle my-task` or `gradle my-task --flag` and be able to check if `--flag` is present or not to define plugin processing.

I cannot find any thing in the official documentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Custom command line options for tasks are available since [Gradle 4.6](https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/release-notes.html#tasks-api-allows-custom-command-line-options) via [`@Option`](https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/options/Option.html) annotation on task property setters. Documentation link: [Declaring and Using Command Line Options](https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/custom_tasks.html#sec:declaring_and_using_command_line_options).

According to the documentation, value-less command line options are supported via `boolean` properties.

> **`boolean`, `Boolean`, `Property<Boolean>`**
>
> Describes an option with the value `true` or `false`. Passing the option on the command line treats the value as `true`. For example `--enabled` equates to `true`. The absence of the option uses the default value of the property.

(Untested) Example:

```java
import org.gradle.api.tasks.options.Option;

public class MyTask extends DefaultTask {
    private boolean flag;

    @Option(option = "flag", description = "Sets the flag")
    public void setFlag(boolean flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }

    @Input
    public boolean isFlag() {
        return flag;
    }

    @TaskAction
    public void doWork() {
        if (flag) {
            getLogger().quiet("Flag is present");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In kt :
    `@Option(description= "My flag", option = "flag")
    var flag = false`

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin you can write the following:

```
open class TestTask: DefaultTask() {
    @get: Input
    @set: Option(
        option = "flag",
        description = "test option.")
    var flag = false

    @TaskAction
    fun run() {
        if (flag) println("FLAG IS ACTIVATED")
        else      println("FLAG IS NOT ACTIVATED")
    }
}
```

Then you should register this TestTask, and then you can call it with Gradle.

```
user@laptop:~/test-project$ ./gradlew my_task --flag

> Task :my_task
FLAG ACTIVATED

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 533ms
1 actionable task: 1 executed


user@laptop:~/test-project$ ./gradlew my_task

> Task :my_task
FLAG IS NOT ACTIVATED

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 328ms
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```